# Change source of image from .cs file

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

How would you go about to change the current source of an image from the .cs file? I've tried this:

file.xaml.cs:

```
BitmapImage yesImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Test;component/Images/yes.png")); // new source address   
img.Source = yesImage; // update source of img
```

The xaml file has a control `<image Name="img" />` residing in it.

Comment: This should work - assuming that the image exists in the location specified. What actually happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working now. I changed the "Build Action" of the images to "Content" and since the images are local to the project i removed "/Test;component/" and I also added UriKind.Relative to the URI object.

```
BitmapImage yesImage = new BitmapImage(
       new Uri("/Images/yes.png", UriKind.Relative)); // new source address
img.Source = yesImage; // update source of img
```